# C++, reading chars into a vector<char> from a file, character by character

Tags: c++, vector, fstream, ifstream

I am trying to read in the first 7 chars of a file named "board.txt" into a vector<'char> but I am having issues for some reason. I am not too familiar with C++ so any advice would be appreciated, here is the code I have so far

```
    //rack
int charCount = 0;
char ch;

ifstream rackIn("board.txt");

while(rackIn.get(ch) && charCount < 7){
    this->getMyRack().push_back(ch);
}
```

And here is the function getMyRack used in the code above:

```
vector<char> board::getMyRack(){
    return this->myRack;
}
```

myRack is a char vector

I tried to test this in my main using this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < test->getMyRack().size(); ++i){
    cout << test->getMyRack().at(i);
}
```

but it does not output anything, why are the chars i am reading in not being added into my char vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't put char in your vector. Your function `getMyRack()` returns vector but not address of your vector. You can add method to your class board for adding char, for example:

```
 void board::addChar(char c){
     this->myRack.push_back(c);
   }
```

And then call this function:

```
 while(rackIn.get(ch) && charCount < 7){
    this->addChar(ch);   
  }
```

Or change the return type of your function.

Answer (score 1):

1. read line one or (how much lines required) from file  to a string
2. create substring of 7 chars from beginning

   ```
      std::ifstream file("board.txt");

      std::string str;

       // to read single line

       std::getline(file, str);

     // to read 7 chars 

     str= str.substr(0,7); 

     vector<char> char_buf;

     for(size_t i =0; i <= str.size();i++)
     {

        char_buf.push_back(str[i]) 

    }
    // use the char_buf
   ```

easier or second way is use

```
            #include<fstream> // for ifstream
              
            #include <cstdlib> // for exit()

            std::string file_name ="board.txt";
            
            std::ifstream input_stream;
           
            std::vector<char> char_buf;
            
             input_stream.open(file_name); 

            if(input_stream.fail()) { exit(0);}

             int char_no=0;
            
           while(i<=7)
                      
            {
             char c = input_stream.get();
              char_buf.push_back(c);
               i++;              
             }
             
           // use char_buf
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string str;
   int char_count=0;
    // Read the next line from File untill it reaches the 7.
    while (std::getline(in, str)&& char_count!=7)
    {
        // Line contains string of length > 0 then save it in vector
        if (str.size() > 0)
            your_char_vector.push_back(str);
              char_count++;
           if(char_count==7)
              break;
    }
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.